# computing a 8 bit checksum in c++

Tags: c++, checksum

I have the following setup where I am trying to write a custom file header. I have the fields which are described as follows:

```
// Assume these variables are initialized.
unsigned short x, y, z;
unsigned int dl;
unsigned int offset;
// End assume

u_int8_t major_version = 0x31;
u_int8_t minor_version = 0x30;

u_int_32_t data_offset = (u_int_32_t)offset;

u_int16_t size_x = (u_int16_t)x;
u_int16_t size_y = (u_int16_t)y;
u_int16_t size_z = (u_int16_t)z;

u_int_32_t data_size = (u_int_32_t)dl;
```

Now, what I would like to do is compute an 8 bit header checksum from the fields starting from major revision to the data_size variables. I am fairly new to this and something simple would suffice for my current needs.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but to strictly answer your question, a 8-bit checksum is usually computed as

```
sum_of_all_elements %255
```

Simply put, add all the elements together, and **sum % 255 is your checksum**.
Watch out for overflows when doing the addition (you can compute partial sums if you run into trouble).

On a side note, a 8-bit checksum is not that good - It won't help you distinguish all cases and it won't help with data recovery; that's why a 16-bit checksum is usually preferred.